# Подбор рандомных значений для связанных переменных

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Такая задачка появилась у меня: требуется подобрать рандомные значения для связанных переменных в определённом диапазоне. Например:

Имеется одна исходная величина - `масса нетто` продукта. И от 1 до 3 величин, которое составляют в сумме массу нетто - `составляющая_1`, `составляющая_2`, `составляющая_3`. Количество составляющих (как уже сказано) может варьироваться. И в сумме составляющие величины дают массу нетто.

```
масса нетто = составляющая_1 + составляющая_2 + составляющая_3
```

Если только одна составляющая величина, то она одна равна мессе нетто.

```
масса нетто = составляющая_x
```

Каждая из величин (масса нетто и составляющие её величины) подбираются рандомно с учётом минимально допустимого и максимально допустимого значения для каждого отдельно взятого продукта.

Например, селёдка матиас. Масса нетто может быть в пределах 120-125г. Составляющие части: гарнир (лук и т.п.) 15-20г., рыба 80-90г., масло 15-30г.

Для подбора рандомного значения использую следующее:

```
$rand=round($products_indicators_min + mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax() * ($products_indicators_max - $products_indicators_min), 1);
```

, где `$products_indicators_min` - минимально допустимое значение, которое можно задать определённой составляющей части; `$products_indicators_max` - максимально допустимое значение, которое можно задать определённой составляющей части.

Но как быть с подбором рандомного значения с учётом других значений? Понятно, что можно создать рандомно массу нетто. А потом также рамндомно 1 и 2 составлющее значение. А после от массы отнять сумму этих двух, получив третье.

```
составляющая_3 = масса нетто - составляющая_1 - составляющая_2
```

Но ведь может случиться так, что третье значение, полученное таким образом, не будет попадать в установленные для него рамки. И как быть в этом случае? Запускать подбор по новой, пока не выйдет толк?

Может есть какие-то решения и т.п. Или быть может кто-то подскажет логику того, как это было бы более правильно реализовать? Ну или может быть кто-то поможет решить задачу? Буду крайне благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый просто вариант здесь - устроить цикл, где прогонять получаемые параметры составляющих веса до тех пор, пока итоговая масса нетто не получится в требуемом диапазоне.